# From xcode not able to execute DISTINCT keyword for sqlite

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, sqlite

-(void) readProductsFromDatabase {
    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;

```
// Init the animals Array
products = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Open the database from the users filessytem
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"db opened");
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT DISTINCT productname FROM iphone ";
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSLog(@"inside sqlite3 prepare");
            // Read the data from the result row
            NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];


                    }
    }
    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

}

My problem is

const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT DISTINCT productname FROM iphone ";

This line not executing ,i am using sqlite3,
thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean by "This line not executing" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is in this step
 NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

instead of 2 use 0